# How to do conditional requirements for browserify?

Tags: browserify

I have some code that I'm compiling with Browserify. How can i create conditional requirements,

for example

const Worker = (node === true) ? require('tiny-worker') || window.Worker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I could find is to use browserify-shim

https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-shim